# How to listen to a change event in all/any of the fields of a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cocoon-gem

I'm using the cocoon gem to add nested fields for `invoice_rows` to `invoice`. For each `invoice_row` I added a dynamic calculation of the total for that row (`quantity` * `price`). That all works like a charm, so when I adjust either the `price` or `quantity` the row_total changes as well.

**Question** 
Now I would like to do the same for the total invoice price. This means that for each `invoice_row` I need to multiply `quantity` * `price` and add them for all rows. This part works on loading the DOM, but I don't know how to trigger a recalculation when any of the fields (`quantity` or `price`) change.

**=>I added the `.field` class to them to identify them, but as they are not unique, I don't know how to listen for a change of any of them.**

**Code**

invoice_form

```
<div class="form-container col col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
  <%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @invoice] do |f|%>

    <h5><strong><u><%= t('.invoice') %> </u></strong></h5>
    <!-- headers -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-3"><b>description</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>unit price</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>amount</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>VAT (%)</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>Total</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="border-invoice"></div>
    <!-- headers -->
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :invoice_rows do |invoice_row| %>
  <div class="reservation-details">
    <%= render 'invoice_row_fields', f: invoice_row %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="col col-sm-2">Total<input type="text" class="field gross-total form-control"></div>


  <div>
    <%= link_to_add_association f, :invoice_rows do %>
    <div class="option-add-option-price">
      <div class="prices-border">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another invoice line
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="border-invoice"></div>
  <p><%= Money.from_amount(@invoice.total, @hotel.currency).format %></p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-6"> <%= f.button :submit, t(".invoice_button"), class: "create-reservation-btn"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

script invoice_form (**that is used to calculate the total invoice price**)

```
<script>
  // $('.row').keyup(function() {
      // var price = [];
      // var quantity = [];
      var result = 0

      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test")).forEach(
          function(element, index, array) {
            console.log(element)
            var price = [];
            var quantity = [];
              // test
            $('.price').each(function(i, obj) {
              price.push((Math.round(+obj.value*100)/100).toFixed(2));
              console.log(price)
            });

            $('.quantity').each(function(i, obj) {
              quantity.push(+obj.value);
            });
            });

            price.forEach((o,i)=>{
            $(".gross-total").eq( i ).val(o*quantity[i]);
            result += o*quantity[i];
            // console.log(result)
            });

            $(".gross-total").val(result);
// });
</script>
```

_invoice_row_fields

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="row test">
      <div class="col col-sm-3"><%= f.input :description, placeholder: "Product or service description", label: false %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><%= f.input :price, placeholder: "Price incl. VAT", label: false, input_html:{class: "field price"}  %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2 "><%= f.input :amount, label: false, input_html:{class: "field quantity"} %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><%= f.collection_select :vat_percentage, @hotel.vat_groups, :vat_percentage, :vat_percentage, {prompt: "Select a VAT"}, {class: "form-control"} %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="field subtotal form-control"></div>

    <!-- </div> -->

    <div class="col col-sm-1">
      <%= link_to_remove_association f do %>
      <i class="fas fa-trash delete-vat"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', '.field', function() { /* recalculate */ });
```

Comment: You are welcome. A few notes here. Why I used $(document)?. Event listeners are lost if the specific element is deleted/re-created, so you must attach to an immutable  parent instead, and unless you delete and recreate the entire html element the top parent listener will always work. Why .on instead of .change? .on can attach to dynamically created elements without need to recall the event listener creation, even if the elements do not exist at the moment of assigning the listener. Basically .on will attach to elements you will create in the future.